# Tiny MCE: use separate config file (for youtube)

Tags: magento, configuration, tinymce

In Magento, there is this `setup.js` file (located in `\js\mage\adminhtml\wysiwyg\tiny_mce`) for tiny mce. This is a file which I don't want to edit, therefore I'm making a separate JS file for the tiny mce configuration.

This is what I got in my `tiny_mce_youtube.js` file.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    plugins : 'safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,emotions,iespell,media,searchreplace,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,youtubeIframe',
    extended_valid_elements : 'iframe[src|title|width|height|allowfullscreen|frameborder|class|id],object[classid|width|height|codebase|*],param[name|value|_value|*],embed[type|width|height|src|*]',
    theme_advanced_buttons3_add : 'youtubeIframe'
});
```

The `tiny_mce_youtube.js` is loaded after `setup.js`. But it isn't overriding the `setup.js` configurations.

Is there something I have overlooked?

### EDIT:

This is my solution:

```
tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.afterSettings = function(settings){
    settings.theme_advanced_buttons4_add = 'separator,youtubeIframe';
    settings.extended_valid_elements = 'iframe[src|title|width|height|allowfullscreen|frameborder|class|id],object[classid|width|height|codebase|*],param[name|value|_value|*],embed[type|width|height|src|*]';
    settings.plugins = settings.plugins + ',youtubeIframe';
    return settings;
}

tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.setup = function(mode) {
    if (this.config.widget_plugin_src) {
        tinymce.PluginManager.load('magentowidget', this.config.widget_plugin_src);
    }

    if (this.config.plugins) {
        (this.config.plugins).each(function(plugin){
            tinymce.PluginManager.load(plugin.name, plugin.src);
        });
    }

    var settings = this.getSettings(mode);
    tinyMCE.init(this.afterSettings(settings));
}
```

Comment: I know this is in French but I've made a tutorial for this kind of problem...maybe it can help you. http://www.pierrefay.fr/rajouter-editeur-tinymce-formulaire-magento-926

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that there might be some string like:

```
wysiwygblock_content = new tinyMceWysiwygSetup(
```

which configures tinyMce. So referer to setup.js to see how it is configured.

Comment: I'm not that good at Javascript prototype. I've edited my first post, but that code doesn't seem to work. Any Javascript prototype guru's here?

Comment: LOL, funny pic. Luckily it only look us at least 2 hours to fix this. Solution can be found in the main/first post.